# Return string without using a template in Nette PHP framework

Tags: php, nette

What is the best way to return a json string or a simple text on screen in nette php framework without loading the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use method `sendJson($data)` in your presenter.

```
function renderDefault()
{
    $data = ['hello' => 'world'];
    $this->sendJson($data);
}
```

Will output `{"hello":"world"}` with `application/json` Content-Type

Comment: Thanks a lot grez what of a basic text. The nette framework doesn't explain this so well.

Comment: If you look at [source code](https://api.nette.org/2.3/source-Application.UI.Presenter.php.html#601-610) of `sendJson` you can see it only does `$this->sendResponse(new Responses\JsonResponse($data));` so for simple text just need another type of response - `TextResponse`

=> `$this->sendResponse(new TextResponse($data));`